# Ubuntu user credentials, file permissions

Tags: permissions, samba, root, users

I am using Ubuntu 10.10 for web development by using the symfony framework.

Normally I install Ubuntu Lamp (Turnkey edition), log in as root and configure all the necessary software in the server needed to work with symfony. (Samba, symfony etc..)

The problem is when I am root the file permissions are not set right for the Samba and symfony systems. All things I do/create in the terminal (CLI) of Ubuntu create file permissions for the user root. Off course I know how to change them afterwards but that takes up time I could spend programming.

When ready I am using the box via my network, creating several site directories directly from my PC on the server. There are multiple sites on this developer server as directories under `/var/www/` there are no virtual hosts.

My question is how to create or set a user after installation of Ubuntu with the right credentials and rights?

Answer (score 3):

With ACL, you can create a group for that purpose and add the user to the group, so that getting the right stuff to each new user is as simple as this:

```
sudo usermod -a -G developers $username
```

That takes a little work, though, to start. This is for Ubuntu 10.10 at least.
First mount the file systems with the acl option in /etc/fstab.

```
sudo vim /etc/fstab
```

UUID=xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx / ext4 defaults,acl 0 1

```
sudo mount -o remount,acl /
```

Then make a group to which a user may belong for this purpose.

```
sudo groupadd developers
sudo usermod -a -G developers $username
```

The user needs to log out and in again to become a member of the developers group.

Of course, do not do this if you have content in the /var/www directory that you want,
but just to illustrate setting it up to start:

```
sudo rm -rf /var/www
sudo mkdir -p /var/www/public
sudo chown -R root.developers /var/www/public
sudo chmod 0775 /var/www/public
sudo chmod g+s /var/www/public
sudo setfacl -d -m u::rwx,g::rwx,o::r-x /var/www/public
```

Then replace references to "/var/www" with "/var/www/public" in a config file and reload.

```
sudo vim /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 reload
```

If we wanted to restrict delete and rename from all but the user who created the file:

```
sudo chmod +t /var/www/public
```

This way, if we want to create directories for frameworks that exist outside the
Apache document root or maybe create server-writable directories, it's still easy.

Apache-writable logs directory:

```
sudo mkdir /var/www/logs
sudo chgrp www-data /var/www/logs
sudo chmod 0770 /var/www/logs
```

Apache-readable library directory:

```
sudo mkdir /var/www/lib
sudo chgrp www-data /var/www/lib
sudo chmod 0750 /var/www/lib
```

Comment: It's preferable to use `adduser` and `addgroup` rather than `usermod` and `groupadd` in Ubuntu.

Comment: Really - why? Both 'adduser' and 'addgroup' are both symbolic links to 'useradd' and 'groupadd' respectively. No difference.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of logging in as root, try logging in as the www-data user, which is what ubuntu uses when running apache.  That should provide the appropriate permissions automatically while obeying the principle of least permissions (you should always avoid doing things as root).